# How to reference another project to a MVC5 ASP.NET app with DNX46

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.6

I hope anybody can help me.
I started to create a new MVC5 website with DNX46. The website works pretty good, if I add the business and data layer in the main web project. But now is time to move the EF repositories and the data objects to seperate projects. And this is my problem.

--VS 2015 Update 3

--Web project with SDK 1.0.0-rc1-update1

```
project.json in web project:
"dependencies": {
"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Localization": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
"DataProject": "1.0.0-*" //line 33
},
  "frameworks": {
"dnx46": {
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

The new library projects are created as normal DLLs with dnx46.

```
"dependencies": {  },
"frameworks": {
"dnx46": {
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

}

After linking the project as reference, shows the main web project a reference error NU1001 The dependency DataProject >= 1.0.0-* could not be resolved.    project.json    33

I have no idea what's happend and how can I solve that issue. I tried to change the used framework in the libraries from dnx46 to net451, but without success.

A downgrade to net451 is no longer possible, because the app uses functions from the new dnx46.

Has anybody an helpful idea to fix the reference problem?

Demo-Project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y0am5u52d2vzl2c/ASPNETCoreWebApp.zip?dl=0

Thanks Toni

Comment: Your question is stating that adding "DataProject" is creating the issue, but your demo project doesn't contain any "DataProject" and it builds just fine. Could you clarify what the demo project is supposed to demonstrate?

Comment: Hi Will, the demo project contains instead another class library project, but the scenario is the same. The project is successful referenced, but the namespace and the class "Class1" is not accessible in main web project. Toni

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to reproduce this - I was able to create an instance of `Class1` without issue in the main project. :/

Comment: is the "DataProject" hosted in the same solution? with a shared global.json above it?

Comment: I found meanwhile the problem. The shared project works pretty good. I had created my main project with an older version of DNX4.6 (I mean Beta 1). The project file of the web project does not contains the xml node <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>. That the rason of the problem.

Kind regards Toni